# Proof Verification for GTM Hungerford Ch $3.1$ #$13$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

In a ring $R$ the following conditions are equivalent:

(a) $R$ has no nonzero nilpotent elements.

(b) If $a \in R$ and $ a^2=0$, then $a = 0$.

Proof:

$\Longrightarrow$ is trivial.

$\Longleftarrow$ Let $a^{2^k}=0$. Then $0 = a^{2^k} = (a^{2^{k-1}})^2$ and by (b), $a^{2^{k-1}} = 0$ This process can be repeated (factoring out a $2$ from the exponent each time) until we have $a^2 = 0$ and by (b) $a = 0$. Let $a^m = 0$ where $m$ is not a power of two. Since $m < 2^m$ for all natural $m$ by induction and $a^m = 0$, $a^{2^m} = 0 $ and by the process before we have $a = 0$.

It seems like a similar argument would work if (b) was the stronger statement: If $a \in R$ and $a^k = 0$, then $a = 0$ (where $k \in \mathbb{N}$).

Comment: Yes that works except for $k=1$.

Comment: Oh yes I see that. I am also wondering if there are other more general statements for this since it seems like there is something stronger going on here that doesn't need this much restriction.